# Identity in cohomology, computation of $j^*j_* \phi$

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a closed oriented manifold with $\dim X = n$ and $j : Z \to X$ embedding of the closed oriented submanifold with $\dim Z = r$. Let $\phi \in H^k(Z,\mathbb R)$. I want to check the identity
$$\phi \smile j^* PD_{X}^{-1} j_* [Z]_Z = j^* PD_X^{-1} j_* (\phi \frown [Z]_Z)$$
where $[Z]_Z \in H_r(Z,\mathbb R)$ fundamental class of $Z$ and $PD_X^{-1} : H_k(X,\mathbb R) \to H^{n-k}(X,\mathbb R)$ Poincare duality. Hope for your help!

Comment: What does $j_*[Z]_Z$ mean if $[Z]_Z \in H_r(X, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Oh, thank you... I have fixed.

Comment: What does $\phi\cap[Z]_Z$ mean if $\phi \in H^k(X, \mathbb{R})$ and $[Z]_Z \in H_r(Z, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Have fixed. I'm sorry for such a big amount of small mistakes